# How to test uploading multipart form data via postman (File not getting opened-corrupt)

Tags: apex, rest-api, api

URL I am using: https://mydomain--stg1.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v57.0/sobjects/ContentVersion

I am passing headers like:

[image]

Then I have created a json file as mentioned in : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm

Here is the file I have named as "NewContentVersion.json" and I am uploading it as binary body attachment :

--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";
Content-Type: application/json

{"Title":"test","PathOnClient":"test.pdf","FirstPublishLocationId":"5008I0000062dqV"}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="VersionData"; filename="test.pdf"

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......and so on (Base64 encoded string)
--boundary_string--

[image]

-------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx--------------------------------------------

Updating question based on SfdcFox comment, I am using dcode.fr/file-data#f1 "Binary 00000000-11111111" file reader option to get binary data like "00100101 01010000 01000100 01000110 and so on". But what parameters i need to pass in form-data? :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `form-data` option for the body instead of `binary`. Your data isn't corrupted, simply encoded--you're trying to use hex-encoded data instead of binary data, which isn't supported. The data must be uploaded in binary form.

---

In Postman, your request should look something like this:

[image: Example of uploading file]

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I am using https://www.dcode.fr/file-data#f1  "Binary 00000000-11111111" fild reader option to get binary data like "00100101 01010000 01000100 01000110  and so on". But what parameters i need to pass in form-data?

Comment: I updated the question with, please check after "-------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx--------------------------------------------"

Comment: @Rabb When you're using Binary in Postman, you must literally paste binary data. It is not encoded as base-64, hexadecimal, binary, or anything else. In other words, the first five characters you should see in the VerionData area would be `%PDF-`, as that is what a PDF would look like. You would have unprintable characters in your payload, which is why you can't use the `binary` option very easily. Use `form-data` for the Body, and select the file you want to upload.

Comment: @Rabb I added an image to help describe what your file upload should look like. When you hover over VersionData, you'll it it says "Text", you need to use that dropdown to change it to "File". Also, you need to use the triple-dot menu on the top-right  (next to Bulk Edit in my screenshot)  to add the Content-Type.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, sorry closing the question 2 days later as I got corona. I tried the way you showed and i was able to upload 200MB file which using composite api provided by salesforce in their docs, i couldn't upload. But that i will see am I doing some mistake their or i will ask create another question. Closing this one. Thanks !

Comment: @Rabb Composite API has other limits; you should upload one file per request if you need to upload many large files.